# jQuery click function not working when click on image

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$("div").click(function () {
    var CurrId = $(this).attr('id');
    if (CurrId == "First") {
        $("#MenuContent").empty();
        $("#MenuContent").hide();
        $('<img src="images/End_05.png" width="30" height="30"  /> <a id="First"  class style="text-decoration:none;color:black">any </a>').appendTo("#MenuContent");
        $("#MenuContent").show("slow");
    }
});
```

I.e when I click on `div` an image (suppose its name is `mm`) and a link appear. Now I wrote this:

```
$("img").click(function () {
    alert('yes');
});
```

When I click on image (that `mm`) nothing is displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('img')` doesn't account for elements created after it was called. You have to use event delegation to account for them:

```
$('#MenuContent').on('click', 'img', function () {
    alert('yes');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are calling the second function before the image was actually added. Try using
    `jquery.live();` or `jQuery.on()` or `jQuery.delegate()`
not 
    `click()`.

**Note:** `jQuery.live()` has been deprecated.